# Can't decide whether I should use a higher-order function or not

Tags: python, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

SIMPLE METHOD

```
def add(listt, addend):
    sums = list()
    for l in listt: sums.append(l + addend)
    return sums
print(
    add(
    [34,19], 6)
      )
```

WITH HIGHER-ORDER FUNCTION (from a page teaching functional programming)

```
def hof_add(increment):
# Create a function that loops and adds the increment
def add_increment(numbers):
    new_numbers = []
    for n in numbers:
        new_numbers.append(n + increment)
    return new_numbers
# We return the function as we do any other value
return add_increment

add5 = hof_add(5)
print(add5([23, 88]))   # [28, 93]
add10 = hof_add(10)
print(add10([23, 88]))  # [33, 98]
```

Which method is better practice? When is a higher-order function necessary?

Comment: This is rather subjective, but as a rule of thumb, why use a complex solution when a simple one is available?

Comment: I'm not sure either would be better than a simple list comprehension: `[n + addend for n in listt]` [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is handy when contemplating these kind of questions.

Comment: The purpose of higher order functions is to make a function more general, i.e. applicable in a wider range of cases to enable code reuse.